# Redux state is being edited without dispatching any action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an app with react + redux, and the problem is happening in the editing form.

**Description of the issue**

1. click "edit" to edit a document
2. Show the edit form
3. I edit/delete one of the values
4. instead of saving (dispatching an action to save) I return to any other page **without saving**
5. then comeback to the *description* page for this object (where the "edit" button is located)

**Result**

The document is edited.

So, from the Portlets component, when I click on the edit button, I'll `setState({isEditing: true})`:

```
if(this.state.isEditing) {
  return (
    <div className="col-md-12">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-content">
          <PortletForm />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Then I open the `<PortletForm />` component, and access again the data with `connect()`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  let portlet = {};

  const portletId = ownProps.match.params.id;

  if (state.portlets.length > 0) {
    portlet = Object.assign({}, state.portlets.find(portlet => portlet._id === portletId));
  }

  return { portlet: portlet };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(portletActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PortletForm));
```

This is the `constructor()` in the editing form:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      portlet: this.props.portlet,
      addNewKey: [],
      addNewKeyDisabled: false,
      newKey: '',
      newValue: ''
    };

    ...
}
```

This is the `<input />` in jsx where that calls the editing function:

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  autoFocus={index === 0}
  name={Object.keys(key)}
  value={Object.values(key)}
  onChange={this._updatePortletKey} />
```

and `_updatePortletKey()`, where the problem seems to be happening:

```
_updatePortletKey(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    let editedDoc = Object.assign({}, this.state.portlet);
    editedDoc._keys.map((elem, index) => {
      const key = Object.keys(editedDoc._keys[index]);
      if(key[0] === field) {
        return editedDoc._keys[index][field] = event.target.value;
      }
    });
    debugger;
    this.setState({ portlet: editedDoc });
  }
```

So I create a new object, and assign it modified to the state, after some debuggin this is what I found:

- When I'm accessing this function `this.props.portlet` contains the original object
- Right after I return the new keys from the map function (where the debugger is placed) and before I edit the state, `this.props.portlet` **contains the edited key!**.

I really don't know what else to try, before this function I'm not triggering any dispatch or somethig, but I also tried a `console.log()` inside `mapStateToProps()` and after coming back to the non saved document the store **is edited**, I don't get it! I also checked that the parent function does not contain any other function that might be working at the same time... got nothing.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: this is how `this.props.portlet` looks like:

```
{
    country: "AR"
    dev: true
    slug: "document-name"
    test: false
    version: 2
    _id: "5a798e53f2c5340bb08479f8"
    _keys: [
        { newKey: "new key value" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does `this.props.portlet` look like? My guess is you are modifying the original Object without realizing it. `Object.assign` does only a shallow copy (the first level of keys). It looks like the `portlet` is complex due to two keys (`editedDoc._keys[index][field]`). You will likely be editing the original object there, not a copy.

Comment: ey @RossAllen thanks for the quick reply! those are my thoughts, but the Object.assign was recently added trying to fix this. I'll update the post to show the "portlet" shape. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why suggested method to deal with redux is `ImmutableJS` or `immutable-helper` or the kind.

It is very easy to make mistakes otherwise.

Here is what happend:

```
// constructor
this.state = {
  portlet: this.props.portlet,  // you put props in the state
}

// change handler
let editedDoc = Object.assign({}, this.state.portlet);
// here a new object is created, but if the value is not primitive, it is by reference.
// this means, while editedDoc and this.state.portlet are different objects, "_key"'s value is shared between these object.
```

And this is a mistake I have seen many people making. Also, it is a pain to debug such cases. So please use a helper library.

If you insist on using es6 to construct new object, it could get ugly as the nesting increases.

```
// example 1
_updatePortletKey(event) {
  const field = event.target.name;

  this.setState({
    portlet: {
      ...this.state.portlet,
      _keys: this.state.portlet._keys.reduce((agg, el) => {
        const key = Object.keys(el); 
        // btw, what are you trying to do here !! (my logic might be slightly off, as I didn't fully understood the transformation, but you get the idea, right?)
        if(key[0] === field) { 
          return [...agg, {...el, [field]: event.target.value}]
        }
        return [...agg,el]
      }, [])
    }
  })
```

Comment: hi! @kra3 ! thanks! I thing the problem lies there, because I didn't know about the posibility of assigning a reference when using object assign. But before debugging this error, I was using it like that, meaning: let editedDoc = this.state.portlet.
But I guess the problem might be happening in the mapStateToProps. where I do:
`portlet = Object.assign({}, state.portlets.find(portlet => portlet._id === portletId));` 
I this possible? because If I do:
`portlet = state.portlets.find(portlet => portlet._id === portletId);` then I'm having the same issue. What would you suggest in this case?

Comment: That was awesome! @kra3 and it worked perfectly, it's the solution I was looking for. Now, I'm not really familiar with the syntax here, could you please explain a little bit? I'm kind of new with ES6, but this is what I think I got: you create a new object, assign all the values with the spread operator, and the second param... selects the value to edit? why the `[]` after the reduce()? Thanks!!

Comment: no, not in the `mapStateToProps`. components.props are like a readonly copy just for the component.

Comment: Your problem was a deep cloning issue. Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone

Comment: In my sample answer, I did went through each nested object and created a new copy.  `Object.assign({}, aObject, anotherObject)` is similar to `{...aObject, ...anotherObject}` . So you could have used that too.

Comment: // why the [] after the reduce() // you could omit it in this case. I just used to put the initial state of my aggregator for clarity. I think you should look into it. reduce can be used to create a single value, another array, object, you name it.